# magento 2 sort child products according swatches in product view page

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, configurable-swatches, product-sorting

I wanna sort the child products of configurable according to display swatches.
I wanna sort the child products in product page.

Product page swatches display like this Green,White,Black
When I use my below code its fetching child products but not sort according to swatches. How swatches sorted and display, and what should I change in my below code ?

```
$childItems = [];
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
            if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
            $imageBuilder= $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\UrlBuilder');
                $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product, null);
             
                foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                    $productStockObj =  $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product->getId());
                   if ($productStockObj->getIsInStock()){
                    $childItems[] = $product->getSku();
                    }
                }
            }
    
     print_r($childItems);
```

When I run above code it displays the child array like this `sku-white,sku-black,sku-green`

I want sort the child items according display swatches